# SQL return only business days

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a Sybase database that I'm trying to pull the current day and previous business day from. I wrote the following, however if run it on a Monday, it doesn't get previous Friday as the weekend gets in the way. Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this?

```
Select distinct price_date
From table
Where price_date IN (convert(varchar(10), dateadd(day, 0, getdate()), 101), 
    convert(varchar(10), dateadd(day, -1, getdate()),101))
```

The convert statements are used to trim the time from the datetime stamp, messy I know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a calendar table. This is because the database does not know which days are working days.

Simply create a table containing every day in the range you are interested in and flag which ones are or are not business days:

```
Create Table BusinessCalendar(
      dt date primary key,
      fWorkingDay bit
)
```

Then you can find the "next working day" like this:

```
select min(dt) from BusinessCalendar cal where cal.dt > @whenever and fWorkingDay = 1
```

You can find previous working day like this:

```
select max(dt) from BusinessCalendar cal where cal.dt < @whenever and fWorkingDay = 1
```

The calendar table could also contain other date-related stuff such as daylight savings etc. which you may need.

Comment: Would you happen to know if this is possible emulate in pure SQL using the Sybase businessday() function?

Comment: @jimmyjames businessday() doesn't know about public holidays.